# Use Matlab to Produce Sound in certain period and export them

Tags: matlab

I am doing research, and this is the final step I need to complete it, but I have no idea how to do it.

I need to simulate the sound of heart rate as beeps in Matlab. For example, if my heart rate is 70bpm, then I need be able to create 70 beep sounds in one minute time interval.

I have been researching it all night long and I am not able to find out how to do this.

The closest I got is:

```
Fs = 48000;
HR = 70 ;  % Heart beat bpm (range 60 - 200Bpm);
pulse_width = 60e-4;
Amp = 0.5;
delay = 30/HR
%delay = ((60/HR)/2)-(0.5*pulse_width);
t1 = -delay:(1/Fs):delay;
Heartbeat = Amp*tripuls (t1,pulse_width);
% plot ( t1, Heartbeat);
% Output signal to heart rate monitor
while (1)
sound(Heartbeat,Fs);
end
```

But here is the problem,
1. there must be some easier way to do it.
2. There is no way I can export the sounds.

Comment: To export the sound, see `wavwrite`: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/wavwrite.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record a sound using `audiorecorder` for a particular number of seconds.

```
nb_seconds = 5;
recObj = audiorecorder(fs, bits, 1);
recordblocking(recObj, nb_seconds);
while (1)
    sound(Heartbeat,Fs);
end
```

Then play it back with `play(recObj);`,  and record to .wav with `x = getaudiodata(recObj);` and `wavwrite(x, fs, bits,...);`

---

As your function `sound(Heartbeat,Fs)` just play the sound `Heartbeat` one after the other, you can just create a vector containing several occurrences of the sound with

```
repmat(Heartbeat,1,nb_heartbeat);
```

where nb_heartbeat = 70 would last 1 minutes.